# Symfony fetch from Many to Many return empty collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entitys- "user" and "event" in a ManyToMany relation. Set a event in the user contoller works fine. If i try to fetch the user, the "event" collection is empty. What im doing wrong?

User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true )
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ewto;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $trainingType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $zoomKey;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $zoomSecret;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $zoomJWT;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $uid;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Events::class, inversedBy="users", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_event")
     */
    private $event;

    public function __construct($username)
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->event = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;    
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEwto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ewto;
    }

    public function setEwto(string $ewto): self
    {
        $this->ewto = $ewto;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTrainingType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->trainingType;
    }

    public function setTrainingType(string $trainingType): self
    {
        $this->trainingType = $trainingType;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRole(): ?string
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    public function setRole(string $role): self
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZoomKey(): ?string
    {
        return $this->zoomKey;
    }

    public function setZoomKey(string $zoomKey): self
    {
        $this->zoomKey = $zoomKey;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZoomSecret(): ?string
    {
        return $this->zoomSecret;
    }

    public function setZoomSecret(string $zoomSecret): self
    {
        $this->zoomSecret = $zoomSecret;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZoomJWT(): ?string
    {
        return $this->zoomJWT;
    }

    public function setZoomJWT(string $zoomJWT): self
    {
        $this->zoomJWT = $zoomJWT;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uid;
    }

    public function setUid(string $uid): self
    {
        $this->uid = $uid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Events[]
     */
    public function getEvent(): Collection
    {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function addEvent(Events $event): self
    {
        if (!$this->event->contains($event)) {
            $this->event[] = $event;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEvent(Events $event): self
    {
        $this->event->removeElement($event);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

User Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Events;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
        /**
         * @Route("/api/user", name="user_show")
         */
        public function show(): JsonResponse
        {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                    'No user found for name '.$username
                );
            }

            return new JsonResponse([
                'id' => $user->getUid(),
                'username' => $user->getUsername(), 
                'firstName' => $user->getFirstName(), 
                'lastName' =>  $user->getLastName(),
                'email' =>  $user->getEmail(),
                'trainingType' =>  $user->getTrainingType(),
                'role' =>  $user->getRole(),
                'events' =>  $user->getEvent(),

            ]);

        }
```

Event entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EventsRepository::class)
 */
class Events
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=255)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $duration;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="event", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_event")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?string
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(string $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getDuration(): ?string
    {
        return $this->duration;
    }

    public function setDuration(string $duration): self
    {
        $this->duration = $duration;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->addEvent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->removeElement($user)) {
            $user->removeEvent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Event controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Events;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("api/events/year/{year}/month/{month}", name="events")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, $year, $month): JsonResponse
    {          

        $date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}");
        $dateStartDay = new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d'));

        $dateEnd = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}");
        $dateEndDay = new \DateTime($dateEnd->format('Y-m-t '));
        $now = new \DateTime();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM App\Entity\Events e WHERE  e.date >= :dateFirstDay and e.date <= :dateLastDay and e.date > :dateNow ")->setParameter('dateFirstDay',$dateStartDay->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->setParameter('dateLastDay',$dateEndDay->format('Y-m-d'))->setParameter('dateNow',$now->format('Y-m-d'));
        $events = $query->getArrayResult();

        
      

        return new JsonResponse([$events]);
    }

}
```

Now i try to fetch the user via  "public function show(): JsonResponse"
But i recived "events": {}"

Comment: probably because your serializing a non-initialized lazy-loaded collection. either use getEvent()->toArray() or let getEvent return $this->event->toArray() (which isn't a collection anymore, but you should expose neither implementation nor internal structures anyway)

Comment: Thank for your help. I have tried your suggestions in the controller and the entity, unfortunately without success. response now looks like "events":[{}]. So still empty.

Comment: that's because only public properties will be serialized (which you avoided in your show() method). one option is to implement the [JsonSerializable interface](https://www.php.net/JsonSerializable) in your Event entity (and maybe in your User too), or you do proper serialization, which may mean more effort

Comment: Thanks, now I understand where the problem is. With the serializer I see the events in the dump(). I still have problems with a circular reference. But I think I can do that, I have to read the documentation first. Thank you!